# Why BigQuery does not show Firebase-Analytics data?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am using BlazePlan and linked my firebase analytics account with BigQuery. Even though it has been more than two days i still can not see analytics data in BigQuery. There are Firebase_crashlytics, firebase_messaging and firebase_predictions datasets but no analytics dataset. Under the Analytics tab in Bigquery page on firebase console, it still says Dataset not created. When will it be displayed in BigQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. Enabling debug mode causes this issue. After turning off debug mode on the device, in ios launch settings, I was able to see the events in bigquery console.

Comment: What did you mean by 'disabling debug mode on ios launch settings'?

Comment: It looks like the question is asking about all platforms and not just iOS. More specifically, are you talking about the -FirebaseDebuger (or whatever it's called) flag?