# How come Firebase Analytics data does not show up in BigQuery?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to get Firebase Analytics data to show up in BigQuery for an iOS app, however the BigQuery dataset is not created, the Firebase BigQuery page simply says "Dataset not created" and the relevant tables are not to be found in BigQuery either.

I can correctly see Firebase Analytics data within the Firebase console, and Crashlytics/Predictions/etc datasets are created in BigQuery (although I can't see the data yet, I think these are only batched once daily). So it's only the streaming Analytics data which is missing.

[This threat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762268/why-bigquery-does-not-show-firebase-analytics-data) suggests that you need to "disabling debug mode on ios launch settings" for this to work. I'm not exactly sure what is meant by that, so I tried the following before running the app and triggering some events, with no luck:

1. Changed `Debug` to `Release` under **Edit Scheme > Run > Info > Build Configuration**
2. Added `-FIRDebugDisabled` to **Edit Scheme > Run > Arguments > Arguments Passed on Launch**

In either case I always see data in the Firebase Console, but never in BigQuery.

Another odd thing I noticed is that the Firebase project is set up in the `eur3 (europe-west)` **cloud resource location** while the Crashlytics dataset that was automatically created by Firebase was setup in the `US` **data location**.

[This (Youtube Link)](https://youtu.be/Ki_F6VCOtXU?t=247) is basically what I'm expecting should happen.

Comment: Strangely, after not having changed anything in the last 12 hours the Firebase Analytics tables have just shown up in BigQuery, it appears that there was just a very long delay in these being created for some reason, although the docs and tutorials seem to suggest that this should happen instantly.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as you describe. If my data too starts showing up within the next day, I would mark an answer as correct if it explains the issue as a delay in the dataset being created.

Comment: @Jez, were you able to configure this to create the dataset in EU region? I can't find any setting to control this.

Comment: Hi @Rahul, I asked Firebase support and they said this is not currently supported, however I managed to get it to work. After Firebase automatically creates all BigQuery tables (in the US region), I then deleted these tables manually in BigQuery and re-created them manually in BigQuery in the EU region (as you can select a region when creating them manually). This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery table creation timing is based on the timezone set for the customer's project/Analytics account.